# in spring framework how to get response from controller to jsp page by ajax call passing an id value to controller

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

In my program i need to perform an operation by passing id.The id is     selected from a dropdown box(ie;changing dynamically).so to pass the id i'am using ajax.but i don't know the code to receive the response back from  controller in spring.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label  class="col-sm-4 control-label">Employee</label>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
     <select id="empId" name="empId" class="form-control" >
        <option value="" >--Select--</option>
        <c:forEach var="row" items="${employeeList}" >
          <option value="${employeeList.Id}">${employeeList.name</option>
        </c:forEach> 
     </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
     <input type="text" name="empname" id="empname" class="form-control"/>
   </div>
 </div>


//i need to pass the employee id from the dropdown box to controller and get     //the name of the employee as response .and set the response value in the text     //box.how can be it done in spring using ajax.
```

//ajax code i tried

```
  $('#empId').change(function(event) {  
                var eId= $("select#empId").val();
                $.get('getEmpName', {
                    id: eId
                }, function(data) {
                    $('#empname').val(data);
                });
            });
//but i am not getting any response ie:nothing in data
```

Comment: Did you want how to call controller via ajax, and also what will be the controller method?
i mean both ajax call along with controller side code?

Comment: @ Ataur Rahman Munna:yes

Comment: I paste some sample code. if that helps then accept the ans. thanks.

Comment: @Ataur Rahman Munna-code pasted is usefull.thanks

Comment: Then you can accept my answer by clicking accept button. :)

Comment: @Ataur Rahman Munna-:in your answer                                  jsonString = gson.toJson("your response convert here to json format"); // here i used google Gson library to convert your response in json format. here  you mentioned that you used google Gson library to convert response in json format.can you please tell me how to import Gson in my project

Comment: of course. you can download it from here. 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/gson/gson-2.2.4.jar.zip
`right click the project-> project properties->add externel jar-> select your jar.`
it would be helpful if you tell me which IDE you used.

Comment: @Ataur Rahman Munna-:downloaded jar files and included it in library folder but at controller gson cannot be  resolved error occurs i am working in spring tool suite

Comment: Sure.
`import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the ajax side code:

```
$('#empId').change(function() {  
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'your_url', // in your controller side (RequestMapping value)
            data: 'empId='+$('#empId').val(),
            success: function(responseData, textStatus) {
                // your stuff here. you found the response in responseData var.
            },
            complete: function(textStatus) {

            },
            error: function(responseData)
            {

            }
    });
});
```

And your controller side code like something below,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "your_url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> postMethod(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String jsonString = "";
        String empId = req.getParameter("empId");
        // your operation done here and 
        //convert it to json format before sending response.
        jsonString = gson.toJson("your response convert here to json format"); // here i used google Gson library to convert your response in json format.

        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(jsonString, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```